# How do you reorder a bar chart

Tags: r

I am trying to reorder my chart so that >£30 appears at the end. This is my code:

```
female_data%>%
  group_by(monthly_spending, Age)%>%
  summarise(Number=n())%>%
  mutate("Percentage"=Number/112*100)%>%
  ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x=monthly_spending, y=Percentage, fill=Age))
```

I have tried fit_relevel but it cant find this function and i have also tried relevel which doesnt work for ordered factors

Comment: change the order of the factor.

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example and someone can demonstrate.

Comment: `... mutate(monthly_spending = factor(monthly_spending, levels = ("first level", "second level", ... , ">£30")) %>% ...`